# How to draw a colored circle around a part of an image with gimp?

Tags: line, draw, gimp

The question is very simple. I just want to draw a simple circle around some part of an image with mouse. Not a fancy circle. It can be not at all a complete circle. I just want to circle around some part of an image to make it stand out inside the image.

As simple as this task is, I did not find any solution on google as it always proposes me very complex tasks like how to draw a circle and the like, which are not at all what I want. The problem is that Gimp is very powerful and so non-intuitive for very simple use cases. Any help will be appreciated as it will free me of doing all these changes under windows on another computer and sending the images via email and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest:

- Make a circle selection with the Ellipse select tool (you can constrain it to a circle by depressing the Shift key **after** you start dragging).
- `Edit > Stroke selection` (use preferably "Line" mode, that will also allow you to make a dotted line).

This said, to annotate images there are better alternatives.